# Change the appearance of the sidebar in beamer

Tags: beamer

I want to make my left-side navigation bar bigger and make the font which the bar uses bigger. In other words, I want it to play the role of the content.[image]

here is my code:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,xcolor=dvipsnames]{ctexbeamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{amssymb,mathrsfs,amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\setCJKsansfont{STSongti-SC-Regular}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\chalkd{Times New Roman}
\setbeamerfont{normal text}{family=\chalkd,series=\mdseries}
\setbeamerfont{alerted text}{family=\chalkd,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{family=\chalkd,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{exampleblock}{family=\chalkd,series=\bfseries}
\AtBeginDocument{\usebeamerfont{normal text}}


\title[]{\huge  ********} % The short title appears at the bottom of every slide, the full title is only on the title page
\subtitle{}
\author[] {\Large *******}
\date{*******} 

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{\gdef\beamer@frametitle{}}
\makeatother

\newcommand\ucite[1]{\textsuperscript{\cite{#1}}}   
\newcommand\hs[1]{\hspace{#1}}
\newcommand\vs[1]{\vspace{#1}}



\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
    
    %------------------------------------------------
    \section{section1}

    %------------------------------------------------
    
    \begin{frame}{Bullet Points}
    0
    \end{frame}
    
    %------------------------------------------------
        \section{section2}
    \begin{frame}{Blocks of Highlighted Text}
    1
    \end{frame}
    
    %------------------------------------------------
    
    \section{section3}
    \begin{frame}
        2
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

- you can use the `width=...` option of the Berkeley theme to change the width of the sidebar
- the font size of the sections in the sidebar can be changed with `\setbeamerfont{section in sidebar}{size=...}`

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[width=4cm]{Berkeley}
\setbeamerfont{section in sidebar}{size=\normalsize}
\usecolortheme{spruce}

\begin{document}

\section{section1}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, you really make my day.

Comment: @李长庚 You're welcome!